# Decompile & Recompile Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

Tags: sharepoint-server, decompile

In my spare time, I decided to browse `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` classes with a reflector.

I exactly want to know:

Is it possible to decompile `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` to do a bit of change and compile it again to add as a reference in my solution ??

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the signed dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, this operation is not supported,
- Second, it's not possible for cryptographically signed DLL
- Third, you can decompile the DLL to `.csproj` that can be opened via visual studio but what I think you will face more errors when you build back the exported project.

Meanwhile, I found an article that mentioned it's possible (I didn't try this before).

The article author use [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) with [Reflexil](http://reflexil.net/) plugin to recompiling the DLL with your modifications.

For more details about this article check [Recompiling your own version of the SharePoint code to suit your needs](http://www.sharepoint.bg/radi/post/Recompiling-your-own-version-of-the-SharePoint-code-to-suit-your-needs)

Comment: `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration.dll` (the article you're mentioning) is a "simple" pure ASP.NET DLL in SharePoint; it's actually built on top of `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` which is the one that does all the hard stuff. I'm not sure the same can be done with `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`, that has a lot of external dependecies, and is the core of SP.

Comment: I agree with you, I have said I didn't try this link before, also I have mentioned all my concerns at the top of my answer, I did a comment to the question owner since 1 hour and said to him it's not possible, but when search about this topic I found this article that said it's possible !!! and use  Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration.dll as example, finally I think we have answered at the same time with the same concerns, so we agreed :)

Comment: Cryptographically signed is the key part here. In addition, there are numerous test harness DLLs that do not ship with the product (among others) that you do not have access to, hence could never compile the project.

Answer (score 2):

The question is, why would you need to do that? SharePoint is a framework that allows you to extend it, and add whatever functionality you want on top of it. There's is no reason why you want to do that, if you want to do something that's not available, Microsoft has provided you with MANY ways to do it.

From the top of the SharePoint hierarchy, such as service applications. You can create your own service applications, and you can connect to external systems and do any kind of development you wish to do. That’s the reason Microsoft built SharePoint as a platform not as a product that you can use as is. So to decompile SharePoint dll in order to achieve something means you’re probably thinking about doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

From a legal perspective, that's for sure not alowed by Microsoft.
From a technical point of view, it's most probably really *impossible*:

1. You won't be able to add external dependencies for the DLL, such as native components it has.
2. Some parts of the DLL won't be decompiled.
3. You won't be able to strong-name the DLL with the same key as Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

By doing this, if you get it working, with a system that Microsoft would refuse to support.  If you require a some specific functionally rewrite it with and adapter class in your code base

Also your recompiled code will break with any service release, cumulative update, hot fix or upgrade of version.  In short you are using an API so get used to doing it the "right" way.